# Javascript - get extension from base64 image

Tags: javascript, image, base64, file-extension

I have a base64 encoded image returned from a service and it looks like this:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4Yp2aHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/Pgo8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA0LjEtYzAzNiA0Ni4yNzcwOTIsIEZyaSBGZWIgMjMgMjAwNyAxNDoxNjoxOCAgICAgICAgIj4KICAgPHJkZjpSREYgeG1.... etc
```

How can i detect / check the image extension?

Comment: this is the image code or image picName/url+picName in base64?

Comment: ok, is the image code, I can obly get this: ÿØÿà JFIF  H H  ÿáŠvhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ <?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.1-c036 46.277092, Fri Feb 23 2007 14:16:18        ">
   <rdf:RDF áµ

Comment: this is the base64 of the image content, you can get the same encoding an image on this site for example http://www.base64-image.de

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a `String` (which you can parse out of an image) you can do this:

```
// Create Base64 Object
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

// Define the string, also meaning that you need to know the file extension
var encoded = "Base64 encoded image returned from your service";

// Decode the string
var decoded = Base64.decode(encoded);
console.log(decoded);

// if the file extension is unknown
var extension = undefined;
// do something like this
var lowerCase = decoded.toLowerCase();
if (lowerCase.indexOf("png") !== -1) extension = "png"
else if (lowerCase.indexOf("jpg") !== -1 || lowerCase.indexOf("jpeg") !== -1)
    extension = "jpg"
else extension = "tiff";

// and then to display the image
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = decoded;

// alternatively, you can do this
img.src = "data:image/" + extension + ";base64," + encoded;
```

For completion's sake here's the [source](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript) and I hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thank you but i can't understand how to return the original image extension

Comment: @sbaaaang If you have decoded your payload, i.e. have decoded the Base64 String that the server returned, you have an image like any other. The only difference is, is that you only have the data in your image. In other words the image isn't stored locally, only programmatically.

Comment: yes but how do i get then the decoded file extension? :D

Comment: @sbaaaang I have updated my answer. I admit it is a little hacky, but it's the only way to get the file extension with the information the client has.

Comment: Why do you define Base64 object, when there are `atob` and `btoa` functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: this didn't work for me. I ended up having this sort of gibberish on the decoded string: "IDATx^흫r鍆P䒲⊖漍&٠೿R+^ú>Ϙ幧�헿 @䂿┳S4" after decoding my base64 image:"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfIAAAHyCA..."
using the method above

Answer (score 123):

A bit late but it seem the question was misunderstood. He just only had the base64 content of the image, not the full data URI.

I wrote here for anyone who encounters with this quest, you can read the first character of content `content.charAt(0)`. By base64 image content if the first char is:

'/' : jpg

'i' : png

'R' : gif

'U' : webp

So for your case, it is 'jpg'.

Comment: I came here looking for this answer. For completeness, **U is for webp**

Comment: While this should be also true for `.pdf` that has the base64 starting with `J`, this is not always true on other image types, as I tested this on TIF files and they have base64 starting with `i` and `T`.

Comment: Adding one more option 'P' : SVG

Comment: What if I wanted to check the videos as well?

Comment: What is the character for TIF?

Comment: 'U' is also for .avi

Answer (score 38):

Was just tweaking with the string. May be this could help.

```
base64Data.substring("data:image/".length, base64Data.indexOf(";base64"))
```

Comment: this is useful in backend operations where image come in request body

Answer (score 34):

You could also do it with a function chain.

```
const type = base64Data.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];
```

Answer (score 12):

A bit late, but you can do it using the [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) module in Node.JS:

> npm install file-type

```
var fileType = require("file-type");

var base64string = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4Yp2aHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/Pgo8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA0LjEtYzAzNiA0Ni4yNzcwOTIsIEZyaSBGZWIgMjMgMjAwNyAxNDoxNjoxOCAgICAgICAgIj4KICAgPHJkZjpSREYgeG1";
var base64string_buffer = Buffer.from(base64string, "base64");

(async ()=>{

    var result = await fileType.fromBuffer(base64string_buffer);
    console.log(result);
    //Returns  { ext: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg' }

})();
```

According to `file-type`'s npm page, it works on getting the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) which can be found in the returned buffer item. For example, a jpeg starts with `ff d8`, a pdf with `25 50 44 46`, etc.

For reference, here's a snippet from `base64string_buffer.toString('hex').match(/../g).join(' ')`:

`ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 8a 76 68 74 74 70 .....`

Answer (score 8):

This one will work for any extension type: pdf, mp3, png, ....

`base64.substring(base64.indexOf('/') + 1, base64.indexOf(';base64'));`

Answer (score 7):

use my js function !
it can check JPG,PNG,BMP and so on.

```js
/**
 * @author PiaoZhenJia
 */
function base64FileHeaderMapper(fileBase64) {

    let fileHeader = new Map();

    //get the first 3 char of base64
    fileHeader.set("/9j", "JPG")
    fileHeader.set("iVB", "PNG")
    fileHeader.set("Qk0", "BMP")
    fileHeader.set("SUk", "TIFF")
    fileHeader.set("JVB", "PDF")
    fileHeader.set("UEs", "OFD")

    let res = ""

    fileHeader.forEach((v, k) => {
        if (k == fileBase64.substr(0, 3)) {
            res = v
        }
    })

    //if file is not supported
    if (res == "") {
        res = "unknown file"
    }

    //return map value
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Mine starts with JTV lol

Answer (score 6):

By the way you provided invalid Base64 string. correct syntax of base64 encoded image string is like this

```
"data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789......"
```

You can parse that string and can get the information out of it

```
const base64str = {profilepic:"data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"};
let mimeType = base64str.profilepic.match(/[^:]\w+\/[\w-+\d.]+(?=;|,)/)[0];
```

[You can see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/fa2otuyp/)

and if you want to get only extensions you can use following code to get that one. using regex to parse base64 string and get the extension.

```
const body2 = {profilepic:"data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"};
let mimeType2 = body2.profilepic.match(/[^:/]\w+(?=;|,)/)[0];
```

[check online working Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/fa2otuyp/1/)

Comment: Simple not complicated and it works, how many times would you have a string like the OPs in a real production enviroment. I just needed the extention i used your option two.

Answer (score 1):

This one Worked for me perfectly. It will return file type in format 'image/png'

```
    function base64MimeType(encoded) {
      var result = null;
    
      if (typeof encoded !== 'string') {
        return result;
      }
    
      var mime = encoded.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/);
    
      if (mime && mime.length) {
        result = mime[1];
      }
    
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above function always returns null

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).