# doesn't able to download image in react using blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I have a QR code that is coming from the database in the base64 format. I have to download this image on a button click. I use this function to download the image on button click. the function runs successfully and I able to download the image, but when I try to open the image, an error message comes in 'Photos', 'Paint' type application says the file is not supported. I use same code for download an CSV data and it is working perfectly fine.

What is the error in this code?

```
export const downloadCSV=(data, filename,image)=>
{

    var downloadLink;
    
    if(image !== null && image === true)
    {
        var dataType = 'image/png';

    }
    else{
        var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

    }
    
    
    var filename = filename;
    
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', data], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + data;
    
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        downloadLink.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `downloadLink.href =\`data:${dataType};base64,${ImageBase64}\``;

Comment: is your base64 string actually a png? which fileformat is the base64 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886677/javascript-get-extension-from-base64-image

'/' : jpg   'i' : png  'R' : gif    'U' : webp

Comment: my base64 string is actually a png.